# Медиа запросы bootstrap4 для sass

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass, media-queries

Помогите разобраться в медиа запросах. Читаю инструкцию на этой страничке:

[Статья о запросах](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Я работаю в sass, создал себе отдельный файлик. Согласно инструкции прописал такое:

```
+media-breakpoint-only(xl)

+media-breakpoint-only(lg)
.dontbuy__reasone
    height: 100px

+media-breakpoint-only(xs)

+media-breakpoint-only(md)

+media-breakpoint-only(sm)
```

Мне необходимо применить для класса свойство, исключительно для размера экранов lg. Я его прописал выше, как вы можете увидеть. В результате, в исходном коде который уже скомпилирован как css я не вижу никаких @media запросов, а просто виду в конце файла вставленный тупо мой класс. В чем может быть проблема?

Я использую sass версию бутстрапа. У меня в сасс файлах подключены только эти файлы:

```
/*Bootstrap*/
@import "../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss"
@import "../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss"
@import "../libs/bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss"
@import "../libs/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может проблема в отступах? Вы используете sass, так проставьте нормально отступы

```
+media-breakpoint-only(lg)
  .dontbuy__reasone
    height: 100px
```

Comment: Плывут глаза. Вы совершенно правы! табуляция...